# Express: Upload file directly to FTP without saving it in the storage

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, express, multer

So I want to upload my file from front end -> back end -> FTP server. I want to upload it without saving it in the back end. I want to directly upload it to FTP server after the back end receives my file.

I am using express.

My current code is:

```
baseServer.post(
  "/api/upload-image",
  upload.single('file'),
  function (req: Request, res: Response, next: NextFunction) {
    uploadToFTP(req, res, next);
  }
);

function uploadToFTP(req: Request, res: Response, next: NextFunction) {
  // sftp settings
  var storage = sftpStorage({
    sftp: {
      host: process.env.FTP_URL,
      port: process.env.FTP_PORT,
      username: process.env.FTP_USERNAME,
      password: process.env.FTP_PASSWORD,
    },
    destination: function (req: Request, file: any, cb: any) {
      cb(null, ""); // designation folder in host
    },
    filename: function (req: Request, file: any, cb: any) {
      // file name settings
      cb(null, file.fieldname + "-" + Date.now());
    },
  });

  var upload = multer({ storage: storage }).single("file");

  upload(req, res, function (err: any) {
    if (err) {
      console.log("Error Occured", JSON.stringify(err));
      res.json({ error: err });
    } else {
      console.log("Files uploaded successfully");
      res.json({ success: true});
    }
  });
}
```

There is an error:

> Error Occured {"storageErrors":[]}

Please help.

---

### EDIT

I changed my code like this:

```
import { NextFunction, Request, Response } from "express";
import { admin } from "../../middlewares/authMiddleware";
import { baseServer } from "../../server";

var multer = require("multer");
var sftpStorage = require("multer-sftp");
const upload = multer();

// sftp settings
var storage = sftpStorage({
  sftp: {
    host: process.env.FTP_URL,
    port: process.env.FTP_PORT,
    username: process.env.FTP_USERNAME,
    password: process.env.FTP_PASSWORD,
  },
  destination: function (req: Request, file: any, cb: any) {
    cb(null, ""); // designation folder in host
  },
  filename: function (req: Request, file: any, cb: any) {
    // file name settings
    cb(null, file.fieldname + "-" + Date.now());
  },
});

var uploadToFTP = multer({ storage: storage }).single('file');

baseServer.post(
  "/api/upload-image",
  upload.single("file"),
  function (req: Request, res: Response, next: NextFunction) {
    uploadToFTP(req, res, function (err: any) {
      if (err) {
        console.log("Error Occured", JSON.stringify(err));
        res.json({ error: err });
      } else {
        console.log("Files uploaded successfully");
        res.json({ success: true });
      }
    });
  }
);
```

The error:

[image]

> Error Occured {"storageErrors":[]}

---

### My server.ts

My server.ts has bodyParser:

```
export const baseServer = express();
const PORT = process.env.PORT;
const bodyParser = require('body-parser');            

baseServer.use(express.json());
baseServer.use(bodyParser.json({limit:'50mb'})); 
baseServer.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({extended:true, limit:'50mb'}));
```

The image uploaded is only 160kb. I do not know what is the problem.

Comment: How do you send the file to the server? Do you use bodyParser in your `baseServer`?

Comment: Yes, my baseServer has bodyParser set in it. Please kindly check the updated question for the detail

Comment: I'm not familiar with multer, but per documentation you must provide just `uploadToFTP` as callback function to route handler in place of `upload.single("file")`.

Answer (score 0):

Finally I got this working:

```
import { NextFunction, Request, Response } from "express";
import path from "path";
import { baseServer } from "../../server";

var multer = require("multer");
var ftpStorage = require("multer-ftp");
const upload = multer();

const storage = new ftpStorage({
  ftp: {
    host: process.env.FTP_URL,
    secure: true, // enables FTPS/FTP with TLS
    user: process.env.FTP_USERNAME,
    password: process.env.FTP_PASSWORD,
  },
  destination: function (req: Request, file: any, options: any, callback: any) {
    callback(
      null,
      process.env.FTP_UPLOAD_PATH +
        file.fieldname +
        "-" +
        Date.now() +
        "." +
        file.mimetype.split("/").pop()
    ); // custom file destination, file extension is added to the end of the path
  },
});

const uploadToFTP = multer({ storage: storage }).single("file");

baseServer.post(
  "/api/upload-image",
  function (req: Request, res: Response, next: NextFunction) {
    uploadToFTP(req, res, function (err: any) {
      if (err) {
        console.log(err);
        res.json({ error: err });
      } else {
        res.json({
          success: true,
          path: path.join(
            process.env.IMG_URL ?? "",
            (res.req as any).file.path
          ),
        });
      }
    });
  }
);
```

I changed the library from `multer-sftp` into `multer-ftp`, because my storage server does not have SSH setup (which sftp use).

For those who have the same problem with me, this solution works.